# Getting: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchIdentifierException: No transform for classification "Transverse Mercator Zoned Grid System" with geotools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, epsg, utm

Using geotools I've been trying to create a referenced envelope after converting/reprojecting from WGS 84 to UTM with specific zones and it seems that either I need to do something with authority factories or figure out some kind of a workaround for this.

Here are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchIdentifierException: No transform for classification "Transverse Mercator Zoned Grid System".
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory.getProvider(DefaultMathTransformFactory.java:290)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory.getDefaultParameters(DefaultMathTransformFactory.java:316)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.createCoordinateOperation(DirectEpsgFactory.java:2610)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateOperation(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:1041)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DirectEpsgFactory.java:1955)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:783)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:801)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.FallbackAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(FallbackAuthorityFactory.java:640)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.FallbackAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(FallbackAuthorityFactory.java:644)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:801)
at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:731)
at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:179)
at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:489)
at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:417)
```

Here is the block of code that caused the error, it is related to trying to use CRS.decode():

```
    MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(aoi.getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), CRS.decode("EPSG:" + epsg));
    DirectPosition2D srcDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D(aoi.getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), aoi.getMinX(), aoi.getMinY());
    DirectPosition2D destDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D();
    mathTransform.transform(srcDirectPosition2D, destDirectPosition2D);
    DirectPosition2D srcMaxDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D(aoi.getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), aoi.getMaxX(), aoi.getMaxY());
    DirectPosition2D destMaxDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D();
    mathTransform.transform(srcMaxDirectPosition2D, destMaxDirectPosition2D);
```

This is what I got when I printed out the coordinate reference system:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N", 
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
  SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", -75.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32618"]]
```

Apparently I may need to set a comparison tolerance when I use CRS related functions, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/CRS.html

Comment: did you use maven to build your project? if not then there will be a missing jar

Comment: yes I did. I also verified that the jar does in fact have a source attachment.